# How to get UIWebView to work properly?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiwebview, webview

I have been searching around the web for a couple of days to find a tutorial on how to get UiWebView to work with the latest version of xcode.

So far all the newest tutorias tells me to control drag my UiWebView into the .h file, but it wont let me do that.

(First Picture) Showing the problem with control dragging.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxlCD.png

Then I tried to manually write the code as seen in the tutorials.

(Second picture) Showing the manually written code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8sWO.png

But it still does not load, just just shows a blank white screen???
Many interwebs to the one that can help me! :)

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You have to configure the view first in order to show something...

Comment: @user1273506:check this [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/12/19/iphone-coding-learning-about-uiwebviews-by-creating-a-web-browser/)

Comment: I'm expecting to see the website?
Pressing a button navigation to another site in the storyboard showing the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is have them both..

So follow these steps ..

- Add a `UIWebView` to the view in Interface builder
- Click and drag from the WebView to the @`interface` class and you will see a small pop up saying add `Outlet`
- Now release the click ..and it will ask you to name the Outlet
- After you have named it(let say mywebView ) ..change

  `[webView loadrequest:];`

**to**

```
[mywebView loadrequest:];
```

Comment: drag from web view to @interface in .h file ... so you have to do : drag from xib file to .h file

Comment: I will not let me do it, the blue line appears but it does not let me place anything there.

Comment: see tutorials on IBOutlets on youtube..also click on File Owner in the xib and make it to the class that is your @interface class..

Comment: There is no thing as a xib and a File Owner, there is a storyboard, and a View Controller.

Comment: click on view controller .. go to attributes in file inspector.. and change the class name to the same class of BogapView...

Comment: click on the ViewController in your Storyboard, and set the class to "BOAGAppSecondViewController".  (Just a clarification on what Shubhank said).  Then you should be able to make your connections, and set your delegate.

Comment: Even I made the same mistake! Thanks for the answer.